# Проблема с перекодировкой

Tags: python

у меня набор текстов, вынутых из старого QuarkXpressa

с кодировкой худо бедно разобрался - в консоли Pycharm все работает

```
    >>> a = '''9 ìàÿ èñïîëíèëîñü 15 ëåò óñòàíîâëåíèþ ïàðòíåðñêèõ îòíîøåíèé.'''
    >>> a.encode('ISO-8859-1').decode('Windows-1251')
9 мая исполнилось 15 лет установлению партнерских отношений.
```

но если этот же код перенести в файл, то получаем

```
a = '''9 ìàÿ èñïîëíèëîñü 15 ëåò óñòàíîâëåíèþ ïàðòíåðñêèõ îòíîøåíèé '''
print(a.encode('ISO-8859-1').decode('Windows-1251'))

9 ??? ??????????? 15 ??? ???????????? ??????????? ?????????
```

и куда это всё покрутить ?

Comment: У меня и файле все отрабатывает без вопросов.

Comment: Подтверждаю, работает без проблем. Файл хоть в utf-8 сохраняете?

Comment: У меня тоже всё в порядке - запустил файл так в PyCharm, так прямо в консоли Windows (`python xy.py`).

Comment: Да, я и проверил кодировку файла. Ничего не понимаю

Comment: Вопросительные знаки могут быть проявлением того, что соответственные буквы невозможно изобразить из-за их отсутствия в текущем фонте.

Comment: не очень понятно, я не смог найти каких тот настроек, различающих "Python Console" и "Run Console". Более того, попробовал на другой машине, которая на первый взгляд настроена так же, все работает. Надо закрывать вопрос, но ясности не появилось

Comment: И если вы попробовали вывод не на экран, и в файл (`print('...', file='...'`) и затем открыли этот файл в эдиторе, о котором вы знаете, что он правильно отображает русские буквы? И попробовали вы прямо выводить какой-то русский текст (`print('что-то')`)?

Comment: первое попробовал. notepad++ говорит, что utf-8, но показывает вопросы, даже попробовал записать файл в win-1251, тоже безуспешно. но уже свалил с работы, а дома все работает :), так что остальные эксперименты завтра-послезавтра